# Performant Way to create checkerboard pattern

Tags: c++, optimization

So I have an image that I want to overlay with a checkerboard pattern.
This is what I have come up with so far:

```
for ( uint_8 nRow = 0; nRow < image.width(); ++nRow)
        for (uint_8 nCol = 0; nCol < image.height(); ++nCol)
                  if(((nRow/20 + nCol/20) % 2) == 0)
                        memset(&image.data[nCol + nRow], 0, 1);
```

Produces a white image unfortunately. I dont think this is very performant because `memset` is called for every single pixel in the image instead of multiple.
Why does this code not produce a chckerboard pattern? How would you improve it?

Comment: Is this a question about performance or about why this does not produce the result you wanted?

Comment: Well, for starters you could replace the `memset` call with `image.data[...] = 0;`, which may or may not have performance benefits but is less ugly and pointless.

Comment: I clarified my question

Comment: What pixel format is the source image? 8-bit RGB? RGBA?

Comment: data[nCol + nRow] should not rather be data[nCol*image.height() + nRow] ?

Comment: I don't think you can really optimze your calls, if not call memset on arrays of 20 elem (since you divide by 20) which will divide the number of calls by the same amount. If your matrix is implemented as a list, you're toasted since two pixels close on the image can be as far as one dimension of your matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better performance, don't treat the image as a 2-dimensional entity. Instead, look at it as a 1D array of continuous data, where all lines of the image are arranged one after the other.

With this approach, you can write the pattern in one go with a single loop, where in every iteration you memset() multiple adjacent pixels and increase the index by twice the amount of pixels you set:

```
int data_size = image.width() * image.height();
for (auto it = image.data; it < image.data + data_size; it += 20) {
    memset(it, 0, 20);
    if (((it - data) + 40) % (20 * 400) == 0) {
        it += 40;
    } else if (((it - data) + 20) % (20 * 400) != 0) {
        it += 20;
    }
}
```

(Replace `auto` with the type of `image.data` if you're not using C++11; I suspect it's `unsigned char*`.)

This is quite friendly for the CPU cache prefetch. It's also friendly for the compiler, which can potentially vectorize and/or perform loop unrolling.

Comment: This only works if you have an even number of columns in your checkerboard.

Comment: Very good! Thanks! Although this creates vertical stripes. there must be an offset of 20 every other "line" I guess

Comment: beware if the width or the height is not a multiple of 20 : you will offset the pattern at each row/col.

Comment: @georgesl Yes, "all squares must be of equal size".

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Nope, you're dead-on actually. Indeed you'll get stripes with an odd number of columns.

Comment: @NikosC. It does not create a checkerboard pattern, but vertical black stripes.

Comment: @tzippy Yep, it's what Frerich mentioned. Try with an even number of columns instead.

Comment: @NikosC. Sorry but I don't quite get what you mean by "columns"? I thought I was looking at a 1 dimensional array here.

Comment: @NikosC. Actually I do have an even number of colums. My image is 1600*1600 pixels which is an even number of 80 columns with a width of 20 pixels. Still I get only stripes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34995/discussion-between-tzippy-and-nikos-c)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I don't think this works for even number of columns. For it to work for even number of columns, I think you'd have to change the increments of i from `i += 40` to `i = ((i + 40) % (20 * image.width()) != 0) ? i + 40 : i + 60`.

Comment: @Alderath Actually this creates one checkerboard line that has an offset of 20 to the stripes.

Comment: @tzippy Ahh yeah, you're right. Didn't think about that. You'd have to adjust for that as well... So when you're about to increment i, if `(i + 40) % (20 * image.width()) == 0` then increment by 60, if `(i + 20) % (20 * image.width()) == 0` then increment by 20 and otherwise increment by 40 like normal.

Comment: @Alderath: Yeah, true- I only recognized the problem with odd numbers of columns and then concluded that it probably works with even numbers of columns. A little optimistic. ;-)

Comment: @tzippy I've added Alderath's solution to the answer and switched to using an iterator instead to get more natural-looking code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image's dimensions which are multiple of the checker square size : 
(I coded in C but it is fairly easy to transpose to C++)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define uint unsigned int
#define WIDTH  40
#define HEIGHT 40
#define BLOCK_SIZE 5

void create_checker_row(uint* row, uint size_block, uint nb_col, uint offset )
{
    uint ic;
    for (ic = size_block*offset ; ic < nb_col; ic+= 2*size_block )
    {
        memset( (row + ic) , 0, size_block*sizeof(uint) );
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint ir,ic;

    // image creation
    uint* pixels = (uint*) malloc(WIDTH*HEIGHT*sizeof(uint));
    for (ir = 0; ir < WIDTH; ir++)
    {
        for ( ic = 0; ic < HEIGHT; ic++)
        {
            // arbitrary numbers
            pixels[ir*WIDTH + ic] = (ir*WIDTH + ic) % 57 ;
            printf("%d,", pixels[ir*WIDTH + ic] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 

    for (ir = 0; ir < WIDTH; ir++)
    {
        create_checker_row( pixels + ir*WIDTH   , // pointer at the beggining of n-th row
                            BLOCK_SIZE          , // horizontal length for square
                            WIDTH               , // image width
                            (ir/BLOCK_SIZE) % 2   // offset to create the checker pattern
                            );
    }

    // validation
    printf("\n");
    printf("Validation \n");
    printf("\n");
    for (ir = 0; ir < WIDTH; ir++)
    {
        for ( ic = 0; ic < HEIGHT; ic++)
        {
            printf("%d,", pixels[ir*WIDTH + ic] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Seems pretty checkered for me :  http://ideone.com/gp9so6

Answer (score 0):

I use this and [stb_image_write.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_write.h)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stb_image_write.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int w = 256, h = 256, ch = 4, segments = 8, box_sz = w / segments;

    unsigned char rgba_fg[4] = {255, 255, 0, 255}; //yellow
    unsigned char rgba_bg[4] = {255, 0, 0, 255};  //red

    unsigned char* data = calloc(w * h * ch, sizeof(unsigned char));

    int swap = 0;
    int fill = 0; /* set to 1 to fill fg first*/
    unsigned char* col = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
    {
        if(i % (w * box_sz) == 0 && i != 0)
            swap = !swap;

        if(i % box_sz == 0 && i != 0)
            fill = !fill;

        if(fill)
        {
            if(swap)
                col = rgba_bg;
            else
                col = rgba_fg;
        }else
        {
            if(swap)
                col = rgba_fg;
            else
                col = rgba_bg;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < ch; j++)
        {
            data[i*ch + j] = col[j];
        }
    }

    stbi_write_png("checker.png", w, h, ch, data, 0);

    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Its a bit slow with large images but gets the job done if you cache them